# How to Launch and Switch between two browsers(not tabs) chrome and firefox drivers in Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, browser, webdriver

```
@Test
    public void openWeb() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\resources\\config.properties");
        property = new Properties();
        property.load(fis);
        
        WebElement UsernameField = driver.findElement(By.name(property.getProperty("username_fieldName")));
        WebElement PasswordField = driver.findElement(By.name(property.getProperty("password_fieldName")));
        WebElement SubmitButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getProperty("submit_ButtonXpath")));
        
        UsernameField.click();
        UsernameField.sendKeys("test");
        PasswordField.click();
        PasswordField.sendKeys("!TEST");
        
        SubmitButton.click();
        
        //Testcase TC_1.01 Verify the login of "Berater" with valid credentials
        WebElement Einladen = driver.findElement(By.className(property.getProperty("HomeScreen_EinladenClass")));
        boolean Homescreen = Einladen.isDisplayed();
        
        extentTest = extent.startTest("TC_1.01 - Verify the login of \"Berater\" with valid credentials");
        if(Homescreen == true) {
            extentTest.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Login successful for the Berater");
        }
        else {
            extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Login Failed for the Berater, Please refer the Screenshot");
        }
        
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Einladen.click();
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getProperty("Einladung_LinkXpath"))).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, "v")).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
    }
```

First of all i call here chrome driver and open a link in chrome, now after performing some actions in chrome driver, i need to open firefox and open a separate link, and check the syncronization between the two. But i dont know how to open two different browsers and switch between them.
Please help.

Comment: You will need two instances of WebDriver `WebDriver driver1 = ... ` and `WebDriver driver2 = ... ` In your code I don't see any declaration of WebDriver. Where comes the `driver` from?

Comment: In the @BeforeMethod

Comment: In the: @BeforeMethod
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: In your `@BeforeMethod` add `WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();` with appropriate setup. In the `@Test` you can than use `driver2`.

Comment: By appropriate setup, you mean to define a new webdriver driver2 for firefox, right? And then in @Test i can use both of them by using windowHandles()?

Comment: No windowHandles needed. Each driver has it's own browser window.

Comment: but then how will i switch between chrome tab and firefox tab?

Comment: There is no switch. In the @Test you just use driver1 or driver2 (or both). That's it.